# Azure-Function Deployment kill my running process..can i avoid?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions

I have a few Azure functions sharing same the code. So I created a batch file for publishing my libs. It is a simple bat file. For each of my azure functions, it connects to a host and uses robocopy to synchronize folders.

However, each time I publish, current running functions are dropped. I want to avoid that. Is there a way to let a running function naturally terminate its work?

I think its possible because when I publish, I'm not re-write real running dll, but I copy file in `<azure-function-url>/site/wwwroot` folder.

NOTE:
The function calls an async method without await. The async method does not completed the work when source change. (Im not focus on this problem, thanks Matt for the comment..open my eyes)

Comment: Are you positive that currently running functions are dropped?  The functions runtime is designed to allow functions to gracefully exit in the event of host restarts, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/661e8de8449865139d20fe019f789a65cfe5da33/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/ScriptHostManager.cs#L160

Comment: The function calls an async method without await. The async method does not completed the work when source change. (Now i add on question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions runtime is designed to allow functions to gracefully exit in the event of host restarts, see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/661e8de8449865139d20fe019f789a65cfe5da33/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/ScriptHostManager.cs#L160).

Not awaiting your async calls is an antipattern in functions, as we won't be able to track your function execution. We use the returned `Task` to determine when your function has finished.  If you do not return a `Task`, we assume your function has completed when it returns.

In your case, that means we will kill the host on restarts while your orphaned asynchronous calls are running. If you fail to await async calls, we also don't guarantee successful:

- Logging
- Output bindings
- Exception handling

Do: `static async Task Run(...){ await asyncMethod(); }`

Don't: `static void Run(...){ asyncMethod(); }`

Comment: All Clear, ty Matt i'm changing my function adding await on my Tusk run, i must change also a little logic of my code to return in the Pattern way! Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm curious how the billing would work for non-awaited async calls. Pay for quick return or pay for the full task running time?

Comment: Quick return. However, non-awaited async calls come with the caveats mentioned above and are a loophole that will likely be closed.

Comment: Has something changed since this answer was provided?  I have a simple test function that writes to a SQL table, sleeps for 5 seconds, then writes another entry to the SQL table.  Everything is Async and awaited within the function as described here (including the Task.Delay).  But when I perform any action that causes a restart (stop/start, restart, deploy, slot switch, etc.), I see functions get killed and re-run.  The trigger is an Azure Service Bus Queue.

Comment: If you're noticing new issues, post an issue on the azure functions github repository - the team is quite responsive there.